# How is this value failing my laravel date validation?

Tags: laravel-5.6, laravel-validation

So I am posting to an api controller action, as we can see I have some basic validation:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        $fields = $request->except(['_token']);
        $user   = $request->user();

        $request->validate([
            'log_date' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"',
            'bill_time' => 'required|numeric',
        ]);
}
```

I constantly get: `The log date does not match the format Y-m-d.`

The date coming in is formatted by moment js and shows:

`"2018-11-6"`

**So I am confused how is that not formatted properly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Y-m-d`, the `d` on that format mask applies the following:

> Day of the month, 2 digits **with leading zeros**

So, the value being passed `2018-11-6` fails due to `6` not matching `06`. Either use `Y-m-j`, where `j` is

> Day of the month **without leading zeros**

Or adjust how moment is sending your value.

For full date reference, check http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: No problem! I probably reference that page on a daily basis to make sure I'm using the right format, so definitely keep it handy :P